# Zk Fixed First Tab

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, zk

I have multiple tabs in which I want to fix the first one tab when I scroll left or right in tabs.Zk fiddle provides code [here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3k9t8ee/1-fixed-first-tab) but using javascript. I need to fix first one tab using java.Is there any solution in java?

Comment: Dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16813804/1787809
Even if not accepted, seans awnser is right.

Comment: @NabilA.:  It means we cannot do this task using java.Is it right?